# Convert group by to pivot table

Tags: sql, r, excel, group-by, pivot-table

I have a piece of data I'm trying to convert to an excel pivot table to take advantage of the functionality where you double click on a cell and it generates a new sheet with detailed information.

The current grouping and counting is being done in R / SQL using something like this:

```
sqla <- paste('select Species
              , CASE WHEN "Sepal.Length" >= 5.8
                THEN 1
                ELSE 0
                END LongSepalLength
              , CASE WHEN "Sepal.Width" >= 3
                THEN 1
                ELSE 0
                END LongSepalWidth
              , CASE WHEN "Petal.Length" >= 3.75
                THEN 1
                ELSE 0
                END LongPetalLength
              , CASE WHEN "Petal.Width" >= 1.12
                THEN 1
                ELSE 0
                END LongPetalWidth    

              , count(*) Count 
              from iris    
              group by Species
                , CASE WHEN "Sepal.Length" >= 5.8
                THEN 1
                ELSE 0
                END 
              , CASE WHEN "Sepal.Width" >= 3
                THEN 1
                ELSE 0
                END 
              , CASE WHEN "Petal.Length" >= 3.75
                THEN 1
                ELSE 0
                END 
              , CASE WHEN "Petal.Width" >= 1.12
                THEN 1
                ELSE 0
                END 
              ', sep = '')
sqlb <- sqldf(sqla)
sqlb
```

This creates something like this:

```
      Species LongSepalLength LongSepalWidth LongPetalLength LongPetalWidth Count
1      setosa               0              0               0              0     2
2      setosa               0              1               0              0    47
3      setosa               1              1               0              0     1
4  versicolor               0              0               0              0     6
5  versicolor               0              0               0              1     1
6  versicolor               0              0               1              0     2
7  versicolor               0              0               1              1     8
8  versicolor               0              1               1              1     4
9  versicolor               1              0               1              0     2
10 versicolor               1              0               1              1    15
11 versicolor               1              1               1              1    12
12  virginica               0              0               1              1     3
13  virginica               1              0               1              1    18
14  virginica               1              1               1              1    29
```

Which is neat and readable.  What I'd like is to double click on the 'Count' column and have excel generate a sheet with the detailed info about the rows contained in that cell.

So I use this code to create data to go to excel:

```
sqla <- paste('select Species
              , CASE WHEN "Sepal.Length" >= 5.8
              THEN 1
              ELSE 0
              END LongSepalLength
              , CASE WHEN "Sepal.Width" >= 3
              THEN 1
              ELSE 0
              END LongSepalWidth
              , CASE WHEN "Petal.Length" >= 3.75
              THEN 1
              ELSE 0
              END LongPetalLength
              , CASE WHEN "Petal.Width" >= 1.12
              THEN 1
              ELSE 0
              END LongPetalWidth
              from iris
              ', sep = '')
sqlb <- sqldf(sqla)
sqlb

write.csv(sqlb, file = '~/iris.csv', row.names = F)
```

However, when I try to recreate the neat table above in Excel Pivot Table I get this:
[image]

Which is unusable.

Any suggestions for how to get something that looks like the SQL table?

Comment: Unclear what output / result you are looking for

Comment: @arvi1000: see edits

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're right with R, just need a few pivot options:

- select all your fields as lines
- select count of species as values
- remove sub totals and general totals
- select tabular layout with labels repeated

[image]

Comment: Bullets 1 & 2 are straightforward, Bullets 3 & 4 require using the 'Design' tab after clicking in the PivotTable and using the 'Subtotals', 'GrandTotals', and 'ReportLayout' buttons.